# Find delta for a given epsilon

Tags: limits

[image]

I tried solving the question by substituting $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y= r\sin(\theta)$ , but even that is not helping me in any way.is this the correct way to proceed? Or should i follow any other method?

Comment: "i tried solving the question by substituting x=rcosx=rcos and y=rsin" Sorry but this sounds as if you DID NOT try, actually. If you have, please provide the details of your (unsuccessful) computations.

Comment: hi. i really tried to proceed with the method i mentioned above. i got stuck in a step with too many sin and cos thetas and didn't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: Which part of "please provide the details of your (unsuccessful) computations" do you fail to understand?

Answer (score 2):

It helps ! Let $x=r \cos t$ and $y =r \sin t$. Then $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.  Now show that

$|f(x,y)=|f(r \cos t, r \sin t)| \le 5r=5 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: hi.thank you for answering. can you please provide the answer with all the steps , because  i am still not able to get it?

Comment: @Fred it should be $|f( r\cos t, r\sin t)|\leq 5r$.

Comment: @joey lang: plug in the polar coordinates and use $|\cos t|\leq 1$ and $\sin t|\leq 1$. You get $|f(r\cos t,r\sin t)|\leq 5r$. You have therefore $|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|=|f(x,y)|\leq 5\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<5\delta$. Now choose $\delta>0$ such that $5\delta<0.01$. Get it?

Comment: Hey mundron. Thanks a lot. I Got the answer now